# SQL Server delete query involving two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

So I have tables A and B in SQL Server, and columns a and b respectively. I want to do the following in pseudo-query command, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I want to

```
DELETE FROM A 
WHERE a < 100 "and only if these selected (for deletion) values don't exist in column b in table B"
```

The reason is that I'm trying to delete some data from table A, but it is giving me an error saying that there is a constraint between values in A.a and B.b .

Does this involve aliases? It is confusing..

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this if you are using SQL Server 2005 or newer:

```
DELETE FROM TableA
WHERE a < 100 AND 
a NOT IN (SELECT B FROM TableB)
```

For SQL Server 2000 this should work:

```
DELETE ta
FROM TableA as ta
LEFT JOIN TableB as tb
ON ta.a = tb.b
WHERE ta.a < 100 AND  tb.b IS NULL
```

Comment: I wasn't sure from the question, but given that there were constraint violations, might TableB.b be a foreign key lookup into TableA?  If so, would there be any difference in the form of the delete other than substituting 'id' for 'a' in the appropriate clause?

Comment: Hmmm, i'm not sure I understand.  I agree on your foreign key assumption. This delete would basically remove any records from TableA that were not being referenced from TableB, which appears to be what he/she needs.

Comment: @Abe Miessler, your first query worked just great! It looks like in MSSQL you can enforce a bunch of restrictions..? I've learning MySQL lately, but there doesn't seem to be any of these features I see in the SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, SQL Server does have the ability to enforce data integrity.  While I am not as well versed in MySQL, I am fairly certain that you can enforce referential integrity.  Take a look at these links: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/2248101/Referential-Integrity-in-MySQL.htm, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Comment: @Abe Hmm, well, I could just be confused. Let's take the first command. In my head I translate the first into a command like:<br/>"ForAll (ARec in TableA) Where (ARec.a < 100) And (ForAll BRec in TableB Not (ARec.a Equals BRec.B))"<br/>In other words, it looks to me as if what's being compared is the numeric field in each ARec.a to what would need to be also be a numeric field in BRec; BRec.b.<br/>As for the second, very similar thing; you're joining on ta.a = tb.b so if ta.a is a numeric field, it seems like ta.b also would have to be numeric.

Comment: @Abe So, I would have expected something more like "DELETE FROM TableA  WHERE a < 100 AND id NOT IN (SELECT b FROM TableB)". In other words, I was assuming that TableB.b was a foreign key to TableA, and that, therefore, you would need to compare a TableA record's id.  Clearly your solution solved the OP's issue, but, so that seems to mean I am missing something important.